# Kendo mobile list view template and open new screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

I have kendo mobile list view and when list item is tapped I want to open a new window. How do I get div with touch handler to open new window

view.html

```
       <script type="text/x-kendo-template" id="app-item-template">
            <div  data-role="touch" data-enable-swipe="1" data-bind="events : {swipe: swipeHandler, tap: tapHandler}">                                     
                    <div>
                        <span data-bind="text: name"></span>
                        <span class="km-icon"></span>
                    </div>

            </div>

        </script>

        <div data-role="scroller">
          <div id="app-listview"
                 data-role="listview"
                 data-bind="source: dataSource"
                 data-template="app-item-template">            
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

<div id="newWindow" data-role="view"></div>
```

in `view-model.js`

`$('#newWindow').open(); //does not work`

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in Kendo UI Mobile - if you have to go to any screen you will need to make use of the navigate() method on kendo.mobile.Application object.

Take a look at the following demo: http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/m/index#mobile-listview/editing

First view shows a list of products. On clicking any item in the list, we navigate to a editing screen.

In the javascript pay attention to navigate() method

hope this helps.